# Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError on a rails 7.0 docker application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, ruby-on-rails-7

I have the rails 7.0 application dockernized, here is my dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ruby:3.0
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs yarn postgresql-client
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
COPY . /myapp

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000
# Start the main process.
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

When I am trying to visit my entry point I am getting the following

```
Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError in Marketing#index
```

Could it be that webpacker has not been installed inside my docker file? What else may causing this issue?

I also see that there is no manifest.json file, can I create it manually?